# Auntie [em], I'm afraid you'll have to go

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

[em](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/em) - 275 questions.

> Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

What caught my eye was the double-meaning excerpt

> em is a unit of measurement in the context of typography. It can also stand for expectation-maximization in the context of statistics: use the [expectation-maximization] tag instead for this category of question.

In addition to that confusion, people are using it for the `<em>` tag ([case in point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57049361/html-tag-em-appearing-on-live-website-only)), which places wrapped text in italics.

> Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

It is, but there's better tags for this. The preferred tags would be [typography](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typography) or [font-size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/font-size)

> Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

Not really. The CSS tag(s) already cover the general concept. We don't need something this granular

> Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

- `<em>` tag (should be under [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html))
- CSS unit of measurement
- [expectation-maximization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/expectation-maximization) Apparently a statistics model

Comment: Agreed; two indicators of a tag's usefulness is: Is it something that someone would subscribe to; and does it stand on its own as a tag (e.g., is not a meta tag)